# "You Must Define An Input Directory" application loader error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am creating IOS app using phone gap, When i upload my app to app store "You Must Define An Input Directory" Error comes up which i have never seen before, How to provide Input directory? even when i upload my older outdated version of my app that has all ready been successfully accepted it says the same thing ??

can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: yeah i needed to have the latest application loader and the latest updates on my mac that was all

Answer (score 1):

I know this has nothing to do with the file because anything that select returns the same error.
A week ago I did an upload normally with the 2.4.1 version of the application loader, but now it seems that Apple has restricted upload to the latest versions of the AL and XCode.
If you can upgrade, do it, otherwise (like me), wait, but can be long.